# Simple UML tools

Tags: uml, visio, sequence-diagram, tool-uml

I am looking for a simple UML-tool that will let me do for example a sequence diagram quicker and better than Word from scratch (Without spending to much time on learning the tool, and with the tool more supporting me than constraining me)

Primary choice is Visio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have used many options available in the market for drawing. If asked personally, [Visio](http://www.visiotoolbox.com/2010) is one of the best diagramming software that I have ever used. I am using it for drawing ER and UML diagrams from past 8 months.

Answer (score 4):

Try Use Online Versions Sometime , It's Lite And Saved My Brain From Blow-up Many Times When I Was Out With No Tools , If U Need Simple One I Suggest This But Search Out Many Online Tools Available

http://www.websequencediagrams.com/

LucidChart WebBased Is Also Really Awesome ( Free Account With Some Limitations )

http://www.lucidchart.com/

Desktop -

Eclipse UML2 Tools Is Perfect If u Need Desktop Version

Rise Is Great And Freeware For C# Also Simple Sequence Diagrams

http://www.risetobloome.com/

**And**As Sometimes People Need UML For Managing Mind Thoughts And Ideas If U Do , As I See U Point At Visio And Word , Try Find Some Mind Management ( Just Thought )

MindApp Is Fastest And Easiest , I Like It So Much

Answer (score 0):

"Simple UML" is a contraction in terms :). But I like [Enterprise Architect](http://www.sparxsystems.com/products/ea/index.html). It's not free, but it's not a hojillion dollars either. You might also take a look at the list [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unified_Modeling_Language_tools).

Answer (score 0):

VS 2010 Ultimate has support for diagrams.  You can even generate sequence diagrams.  [Here](http://www.devcurry.com/2010/03/generate-sequence-diagrams-in-visual.html) is a blog post about doing so (no affiliation).